# Is there a way to not start an Anylogic simulation from scratch every time?

Tags: anylogic

Good day

I'm a new user trying to find my with Anylogic.

Any help with the following question will be appreciated.

1. Is it possible to start a model with initial values/quantities given to certain blocks/sections in a model? In other words not have the model start from 0 but from the values given.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a "warmup" period manually and save that as a model snapshot. In future runs, you can start off from that snapshot by loading it. See the help on model snapshots

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Will it also allow me to manually insert values for the simulation to start off with?

Comment: no, youd have to do this yourself via injection

Comment: Okay thank you is injection a common practice on anylogic, will i find information on it?

Comment: im I on the right track with this sintax? "void inject()" im trying to insert it at the "on enter" actions of a convey block.

Comment: no, typically you use the "Enter" block and manually feed it with agents that you created beforehand (using "myEnterBlock.take()" method)

Comment: thanks Bengamin. Do I insert that statement in the actions settings of the conveyor enter block?

Comment: Jip not much assistance starting from scratch on the learning addition. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general problem of model initialisation (e.g., if you're modelling a manufacturing facility, you may want the run to start with the facility at the state it would be at on 9am next Monday morning). There is no generic answer: what initialisation you need is 100% model-dependent (as is how easy/hard this is).

In particular, process models make this difficult because entities (agents) are expected to have flowed through the process up to the point they 'start' in. You can use things like extra initialisation-only Source/Enter blocks to 'inject' agents into the appropriate process points, but in most models it's not this easy: you will have all kinds of model state that needs to be made consistent with this (e.g., the agents flowing through the process might have attributes which have changed based on what's happened to them so far, so this would have to be made consistent).

That's why warm-up periods (letting the model run 'from empty' for a period until its state is qualitatively what you want as your starting point) is a common approach. Model snapshots can help you here (see Ben's answer) but they're not the only way of doing it. (You can also just 'reset' all your metrics/output gathering at the point when you determine the warm-up period has ended --- i.e., you are effectively establishing a new 'time zero' --- but, again, exactly what you need to do is 100% model dependent.)